# pymongo query not returning anything in flask

Tags: flask, pymongo

So I have api.py (flask restplus api) and I have code to query my database and return results. results is empty when I print it and I have no idea why. The query code works in another file that is not api-based, so I speculate it has something to do with the api. Any ideas for what to do?

```
 results = list(diseases_collection.find({
                    "date_of_publication":{
                        '$gte':start_date.replace("T", " "),
                        '$lte': end_date.replace("T", " ")
                    }
                }))                        
 print(results)
 return jsonify(results)
```

Comment: Can you try with `dateutil.parser.parse(start_or_end_date)` for `'$gte'` and `'$lte'` fields instead of string.

Comment: Hi sid, i get dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: "2009-10-01T08:45:10"

Comment: Can you print the string `start_date` and `end_date` what exactly the value for them? I think there are some unwanted characters for that date parsing is failing. Try printing `print([c for c in start_date])`. that will show each bytes.

Comment: Also try adding `fuzzy=True` in parser `dateutil.parser.parse(start_or_end_date, fuzzy=True)`.

Comment: ['"', '2', '0', '0', '9', '-', '1', '0', '-', '0', '1', 'T', '0', '8', ':', '4', '5', ':', '1', '0', '"']

Comment: Ahh!! There it is... `start_date` and `end_date` contains `"` at beginning and ending. Just remove them everything will be fine. `dateutil.parser.parse(start_or_end_date, fuzzy=True)` that also should work fine and pass the output as `'$lte'` and `'$gte'`.

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to clean the user input from API calls.

```
import dateutil.parser

results = list(diseases_collection.find({
                    "date_of_publication":{
                        '$gte': dateutil.parser.parse(start_date, fuzzy=True),
                        '$lte': dateutil.parser.parse(end_date, fuzzy=True)
                    }
                }))
 print(results)
 return jsonify(results)
```